# точку должно добавлять только если в конце строки какой-то символ или цифра?c#/string

Tags: c#

1. точку должно добавлять только если в конце строки какой-то символ или цифра.
   Или по другому: точку надо добавлять, только если в конце нету уже точки/запятой/знака восклицания/точки с запятой.
2. знаков препинания больше чем запятая и двоеточие. Есть еще: !?._;
3. знаки препинания должно заменять(реплейсить) в цикле. Оно должно убирать двойные запятые до тех пор, пока они там есть. Их может быть не две подряд, а 20 например.
   То-есть надо проверять в условии цикла или есть двойные запятые, и если есть то заменять. И так постоянно, пока двойных запятых там не останется. Оно так должно делать с каждым знаком пунктуации (для каждого из них отдельный цикл).

   ```
        Console.WriteLine("Введите строку:");
        string str = (Console.ReadLine());

        str = str.Replace(",,", ",");
        str = str.Replace("::", ":");
        str += ".";

        if (str.Length > 0)
            str = str[0].ToString().ToUpper() + str.Remove(0, 1).Trim();
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
   ```

   }
   }

Comment: здесь дамп домашки не работает: _Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу_

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.char - здесь есть все что нужно для решения этой задачи.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Введите строку:");
            string str = (Console.ReadLine());


            str = str.Replace(",,", ",");
            str = str.Replace("::", ":");
            str += ".";

            if (str.Length > 0)
                str = str[0].ToString().ToUpper() + str.Remove(0, 1).Trim();
          
                

            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }   


    }
}

Comment: не в комментарий, отредактируйте сам вопрос и **напишите, что именно не получается под кодом**

Comment: вам стоит добавить в текст вопрос

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Давайте попробую я, постараюсь попроще

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите строку:");
string text = Console.ReadLine();

// первую букву заглавной, хотя этого в условии нет, но есть в коде
text = char.ToUpper(text[0]) + text.SubString(1);

string chars = ".,?!:;-"; // все символы пунктуации

// поставить точку, если не символ в конце
if (Array.IndexOf(chars, text[text.Length - 1]) < 0)
    text += '.';

// убрать дубликаты
foreach (char c in chars)
{
    string dup = new string(c, 2);
    while (text.Contains(dup))
        text = text.Replace(dup, c.ToString());
}
```

- [Array.IndexOf](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof)
- [String(Char, Int32)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor)

Comment: Отлично ) 
Большое спасибо вам!

Answer (score -2):

```
        Console.WriteLine("Введите строку:");
        string str = (Console.ReadLine());
        if (str.Length > 0)
            str = str[0].ToString().ToUpper() + str.Remove(0, 1).Trim();

        if (str.EndsWith("!") == true)
            str += "";
        else if (str.EndsWith("?") == true)
            str += "";
        else if (str.EndsWith("-") == true)
            str += "";
        else if (str.EndsWith(".") == true)
            str += "";
        else if (str.EndsWith(";") == true)
            str += "";
        else if   (str.EndsWith(".?-.;") == false)
            str += ".";

        while (str.Contains(",,"))
            str = str.Replace(",,", ",");
        while (str.Contains("::"))
            str = str.Replace("::", ":");
        while (str.Contains("!!"))
            str = str.Replace("!!", "!");
        while (str.Contains("??"))
            str = str.Replace("??", "?");
        while (str.Contains(".."))
            str = str.Replace("..", ".");
        while (str.Contains("--"))
            str = str.Replace("--", "-");
        while (str.Contains(";;"))
            str = str.Replace(";;", ";");
       Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Избегайте повторяющегося кода. Повторяющийся код - почти всегда плохо. **DRY** - Don't Repeat Yourself - "Не повторяй за собой"